# How can I insert background image to cover most of webpage?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to place a background image on my webpage section 1 which is more than half of the page similar to this [example](https://jonny.me).
When I try to do this the image doesn't have the right proportion and looks very stretched.

My [codepen.](http://codepen.io/ldocherty1/pen/xqOWBG)

Below is my CSS of me trying to do this.

```
<body background=".png">
```

Instead of body I think I have to put section 1 because, I want the background image to be within my section 1. However when I put this nothing happens. I think I'm writing the wrong class name.

HTML

```
<a href="#">Test!</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add background-image in the CSS file for the body.

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-image: "yourimage.png";
  background-attachment: fixed;
  }
```

Remove z-index to your .navbar.navbar-default in the CSS file.

```
.navbar.navbar-default {
    background-color: #4D5061;
    height: 10vh;
    z-index: 100; //REMOVE. NOT NEEDED.
}
```

Make navbar static to top.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
```

[Bootstrap navbar Static Top](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top)

Also in the code at [My CodePen](http://codepen.io/ldocherty1/pen/xqOWBG) you have `<style> </style>`tags in the CSS file.  I had to remove them for the changes to work correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the help, when I put in my own URL the image doesn't display? I followed all your steps above.

Comment: Here is a link to [My Codepen](http://codepen.io/techdad107/pen/EWyrOR) with the changes.  I used a url to the image.

Comment: Voted your answer as correct. Thanks for everything. If you have time do you know how I can make my nav bar static and move up the background image up to there is no white gap?

Comment: Change your nav class to '<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">' to keep it at the top.  I will edit my original answer to get rid of the white gap.

Answer (score 1):

To the tag where you have the background image, add `background-size: cover`

Comment: What HTML coding do I use because, when I use 'a ref' it hyperlinks text to the image URL. However, I want the background image to be displayed on the webpage.

Comment: define it as the background image for your section

Answer (score 0):

I kinda forgot about the code but you could probably inspect the code from this [website](https://adhywiranata.github.io/) and figure out the answer yourselves. :(

I'm so sorry if this answer is not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should use

> background-size: contain;

this will cover all the available area for the background.

Only disadvantage in this is, you loose your full image, since we make it cover all the available space.

Comment: What HTML coding do I use because, when I use 'a ref' it hyperlinks text to the image URL. However, I want the background image to be displayed on the webpage.